# Dynamically controlling which tests are run by pytest

Tags: pytest

As I'm testing various pieces of hardware I need to adjust which tests are executed based on the capabilities of the specific device under test.  The things is these capabilities need to be read directly from the the hardware itself.  I need my test to read this information from the hardware and then only execute those tests for those capabilities.  One hardware setup might support A, B and C where as another supports B, E, F and G.  All of this needs to be able to be done with no prior knowledge of what the hardware supports.

I've looks at the pytest documentation and questions online but have not come across anything similar to what I need to do as it seems everything is initiated from the CLI i.e. you run these tests with these markers.  I want to run pytest and have it interrogate the hardware to determine what tests need to run and then execute just those particular tests automatically.

I've considered a python script that checks the hardware then launches pytest with the correct commandline arguments but I would prefer to do this completely with pytest if I can.

Is this possible using just pytest and if so can you give an example?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Either pytest is passed a list of tests or pytest runs all tests and tests themselves determine if they are allowed to run. If a test doesn't want to run it can signal to pytest "Skip me".

Comment: What type of hardware capabilities?

Comment: For simplicity sake lets say they are weather stations.  There are 3 models.  When queried the first says it supports temp and humidity, the second supports temp wind direction and wind speed and the third supports temp, humidity, wind speed, wind direction and rain fall.  I want to ask the status "What do you support", get the list and then just run those tests.  This way I can add a fourth station and not have to worry about updating the tests or knowing the capabilities up front.  I would prefer not to run ever test and skip if not supported and this could be a very long list of tests.